# Determining EPSG code for coordinate transformation using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, epsg

I am trying to write a Python script which will identify the EPSG code for the coordinate transformation.

I am familiar with the dataFrame.geographicTransformations function, however this returns a String describing the name of the transformation.  What I really need is the EPSG code of this.

EPSG codes are possible in a SpatialReference Object, but do not seem to translate into the geographicTransformations.

Comment: I think your question will be of more interest to potential answerers if you can include a code snippet that shows what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I agree - if you can post the code you've got, someone may know how to convert the string to the EPSG code. It may be possible to interrogate the http://spatialreference.org page, etc